# How propose a story / write / publish for an established universe or franchise?

Tags: fiction, novel, publishing, science-fiction

I would like to know the process of proposing a story or manuscript for an established universe or franchise. Some examples of universes include Star Wars, Star Trek, Horizon, etc. My question is about how authors previously have written and published for those universes.

I am writing a manuscript currently for a character in this fictional universe. The end goal is writing a book or a novel in this universe. I am not at all affiliated with the original creators of the universe. I am simply a big fan of the universe. And I would like to write and publish a story for one of the characters in this universe whose story is not yet written.

- Do I go through the standard process of getting an editor and then a literary agent?
- Does my agent need to pitch the story and get permission first from the creators?
- How do we reach out to the creators?
- How are rights handled?
- Is there a resource on the web that has all the steps listed?

Any resources or direction from someone who has gone through this process would be much appreciated because I am not at all familiar with the process.

Thank you

Comment: Star Wars has writers? Maybe the original three movies. But I've not been able to detect any story in anything since then.

Comment: Do any of these answer your question? [How does one go about writing "official" fanfiction?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/1790/34330) or [Is fan fiction publishable?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/29976/34330) or maybe [Can you legally write new Star Wars: Legends books?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/34799/34330)

Comment: Star Wars has multiple writers in Legends apart from the original 3 films before Disney bought LucasFilms and declared their works as part of Legends.  I am just trying to understand how those writers broke through.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you don't do this.

The universe is somebody else's Intellectual Property. It is typically worth a great deal of money, and is often still being exploited by the owners. That can include authors and their publishers that have the copyrights.

They will sue you to high heaven for copyright and trademark violations if you try to use their universe, for any reason, even if you aren't making a profit.

The only people that get to write for such a Universe must be approved by the copyright holders. And typically, best selling authors and publishers will NOT use anybody that is not **already** a best-selling author, as a collaborator.

When JK Rowling was involved in making movies for Harry Potter, she had the final say over everything and was involved with the screenwriter every step of the way, approving every line. And this was a screenwriter with many years of experience and writer of produced screenplays. She chose him, and supervised him, discussed the scripts and answered his questions (because obviously, the screenplay is much, much shorter than any book).

JK Rowling does permit some non-profit fan-fiction of Harry Potter, following her set of written rules, but many other authors do not. That is their decision.

Intellectual Property is, in general, very jealously protected, because the original authors want to control everything about their Universe and how it unfolds.

Just because your character is not well-defined in their Universe is not an excuse, they may have their own ideas about how to develop that character in future works, and don't want your ideas.

Especially if you are an unpublished beginner.

Sorry, the only way to gain admittance into their club is with credentials, you will have to invent your own story and your own Universe and get that published and make some impressive sales.

**Then,** with some best-seller proof on the table for you, their agent might take your call and they might consider your offer.

Otherwise, this is a hopeless pursuit, begun and abandoned by many, many fans.

Sorry the cold water.